# how to not terminated session automatically in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web-config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">

      <forms name="SignIn" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="9999999" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"/>

    </authentication>
```

This will automatically logout my logged in page with in 1 or two minutes ....

I want my session will not terminated automatically until i logout....

how to do this in web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very nice and simple technique, Reloading an image time to time keeps session live. A random number at the end if the image force it to load it again. If the image did not trigger the session, then you can change it with a handler that return the same image.

```
<img id="keepAliveIMG" width="1" height="1" src="/img/ui/spacer.gif?" alt="" /> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    var myImg = document.getElementById("keepAliveIMG");

    if (myImg){
        window.setInterval(function(){
              myImg.src = myImg.src.replace(/\?.*$/, '?' + Math.random());
            }, 6000);
    }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should use cookies. I prefer using this method:

After user clicks login button:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, True)
```

When persistence cookie is set to True, a cookie is created so user will stay logged in even if he closes his session.

My web.config is like:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"  />
```

and everything works fine. In sample above the user will stay logged in for 2880 minutes.

Have a look at these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx